# Limit From the Right: Proving a Limit with Value in the Denominator

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that $\lim_{x\to 5^+}\frac{15(x+7)}{(x-5)(x+2)}=\infty$.

This is how far I have got:

Let $M>0$. Then, $\delta=\text{something..}$.

Assume $0<x-5<\delta$. Show $\frac{15(x+7)}{(x-5)(x+2)}>M$. Now, the temptation is to get $(x-5)$ by itself. However, in doing so, the value for $\delta$ would be a function of $x$ which is not what I want...

What is the best way to proceed with this? I am looking for a generalizable way for proving these results with polynomial functions with roots in the denominator that look like this (i.e. they are not removable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $\frac  {x+7} {x+2} >1$ for al $x >0$. So you only need $\frac {15} {x-5} >M$ and this shoud be quite easy.

Comment: You could go one step further and say $\frac{15(x+7)}{x+2} > 1$ and substitute $(x - 5) = t$.